# Angular 9 : How you would design your app to allow domain mapping with SEO in mind (let's say Wordpress.com or wix-like functionality)?

Tags: angular

I am considering adding capabilities of a website generator to my Angular 9 website.

Ex: `mydomain.com/thecustomerhandle`

It will be 3 pages :

```
mydomain.com/thecustomerhandle ('almost'-one pager)
mydomain.com/thecustomerhandle/contacts
mydomain.com/thecustomerhandle/terms
```

For those who already did it what are best practices for :

**Routing**

I want to keep simple urls. How to make

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule),
  },
```

works with

```
mydomain.com/thecustomerhandle1, 
mydomain.com/thecustomerhandle2,
mydomain.com/thecustomerhandle3,  
.
```

**Domain mapping**

Other best practices for isolating the customer website for SEO after domain mapping:

Be sure that in google there is :

```
thecustomerhandle3.com
```

and not `mydomain.com/thecustomerhandle3`,

Thanks a lot !

I didn't find such information or a tutorial about that topic on Google.

EDIT : Im using Server Side Rendering via Express.

Answer (score 2):

As the content in an Angular app is generated through Javascript in Runtime, it can not be accessed by crawlers who (currently) only parse static content.

Angular Routes are a part of client side rendering and thus **not** search engine optimized.

For a properly search engine optimized Angular app you should consider angular universal. Which renders your app on the server as opposed to in the users browser. 
https://angular.io/guide/universal

Server side rendering does come with some caveats however and there are options in between pure client side rendering **CSR** and server side rendering **SSR**.

A detailed comparison of the rendering techniques can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web